# Global temporary table producing the wrong results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a global temporary table:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE "MY_TEMPORARY_TABLE" 
   ("ID" NUMBER(5,0), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS ;
```

On my front end I have a button which populates this table. It takes about 2 minutes for this query to run due to the large amount of data. A user will click the run query button and start to generate the table. 5 seconds later while the first query is still generating the user will change one parameter in the query and click the button again. This will open a new window and start generating the data into the table. Now when both the queries finish the queries will return the same output which means only one query is correct, but since in the 2nd one the parameter changed it should create a different output but it does not? From my understanding the temporary table should keep the data private from each session?

If I click the button the second time after 2 minutes instead of 5 seconds after the proper results are produced.

Comment: You say that you created a global temporary table.  You posted DDL for a local temporary table which is not valid.  Did you mean to have `create global temporary table` in your code?  Beyond that, I'm not sure that I understand the problem you are describing.  You have a global temporary table.  You have two sessions.  Each session's data is private so each session will populate a separate set of rows.  Assuming you query the data in the same session as part of the same transaction that it is generated, you should be able to see both versions of the data.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the "query" you have shown does not take 2 minutes to run (a create table without a select statement only takes a fraction of a second). You need to show us the actual query that _uses_ that temp table and the execution plan for that. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)